# Center of volume and volume for triangle wedge

Tags: geometry, volume, centroid

Let's say we have a wedge, where the base is a triangle, parallel with the $xy$-plane, and where only one of the sides extends perpendicular to the base:

[image: Perspective view of triangle wedge]

Here is the same wedge, looking down the Z-axis:

[image]

We know:

- The vertices of the triangle, $B$, $L$ and $R$
- The height $h$ of the extending side
- Then also the base area $A$ and centroid $C$, I'm sure

**Questions**

- How can we calculate the volume of the wedge?
- How can we calculate the center of volume, $C_{V}$?

*PS. I'm a layman at math. Sorry if this is overly trivial, badly worded or inappropriate.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the volume:

$$V=\frac13 A\cdot h$$

For the centroid, denote with U the up vertex, by vectors:

$$C_v={B+L+R+U\over 4}$$